# Xcode swift method completion does not promoted anything after stroke the [tab] key

Tags: xcode, swift, ide, code-completion

Despite so much advantages of swift lang, one of the reason I did not adopt swift code is its bad code completion support with Xcode.

Here are two scenarios to better describe my question.

**Scene 1:**

During daily app development, I may come across quite a few protocol methods. Take the following UITableViewDataSource method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

for example, after typing

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
```

, I will normally type [tab] key, but there are nothing to promote in swift lang.

while things go smoothly in Objective-C:
[image]

So most of the cases, I have to jump to UITableView(wait a 1-2 secs for Xcode to generate swift header), and copy the method needed, then paste it the place I was coding.

By the way, if you [command + left] the method pasted above, Xcode has no idea what the function is, and where it is defined.

**Scene 2:**

To tweak animation, I need to change a method to an alternative one with more args.

```
//from
class func animateWithDuration(duration: NSTimeInterval, animations: () -> Void)
//to
class func animateWithDuration(duration: NSTimeInterval, animations: () -> Void, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
```

In Objective-C, I gonna stroke [tab] before the last closing parenthesis, everything works fine. When I do this in swift, just a tab(four blanks) will appear.

**My questions are:**

1. How do you accomplish the two scenes I described above?
2. Are there some better way to do the same job for swift?(Maybe a plugin available out there, or any other helpful tips)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something I also despise while writing code in swift. There is no great way to do this, therefore you have to choose your method before you let it autocomplete.

For both scenario 1 and 2, you would have to type the first letters of `tableView` and `animateWithDuration` respectively, and use the up and down arrows to choose your method, and hit tab to finish the entire method.

The plus of swift is that it will automatically fill in `func` or `class func`, but after you fill in the methods, you can't add or remove parameters.

So far I can't find an easier way to do this. You'll have to wait for apple to improve their autocomplete.